# List all open TCP connections Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there any Rust Lib or Libc primitive to get a list of all open TCP connections on the machine? I don’t want to bind to a Linux binary by running a Linux command such as `ss` or `netstat`.

Comment: The [procfs](https://docs.rs/procfs/latest/procfs/net/fn.tcp.html) crate will do that via the `procfs` filesystem on Linux

Answer (score 1):

As @user2722968 pointed out, you can use it like this:

```rust
use procfs::net::tcp;

fn main() {
    for entry in tcp().unwrap().iter() {
        println!("{:?}", entry);
    }
}
```